# How to create a stacked area chart in R over time (24 hours)?

Tags: r, data-visualization

I'm trying to create a stacked area chart in R Studio to represent my productivity in different areas of my life over a normal 24 hour day.

Here's a snipped of my dataset:

```
Time   Coursework    Leisure Intern    PD 
 1 00:00           0       0      0     0     
 2 01:00           0       0      0     0    
 3 02:00           0       0      0     0     
 4 03:00           0       0      0     0     
 5 04:00           0       0      0     0    
 6 05:00           1       0      0     0     
 7 06:00           1       0      0     2     
 8 07:00           6       1      0     6    
 9 08:00          17       1      0     1   
10 09:00          18       0      0     1
```

The part I'm struggling most with is how to format my CSV file and group all this data together.  I'm totally lost in how to frame this data in the context of a 24-hour day. Can anyone please help me get started with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changing @Duck 's to area and using `tidyverse` to simplify data definition:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

df <- tribble(
~rn,  ~RecordTime, ~Coursework,    ~Leisure, ~Intern,    ~PD,
  1,  "00:00",           0,       0,           0,      0,     
  2,  "01:00",           0,       0,           0,      0,    
  3,  "02:00",           0,       0,           0,      0,     
  4,  "03:00",           0,       0,           0,      0,     
  5,  "04:00",           0,       0,           0,      0,    
  6,  "05:00",           1,       0,           0,      0,     
  7,  "06:00",           1,       0,           0,      2,     
  8,  "07:00",           6,       1,           0,      6,    
  9,  "08:00",          17,       1,           0,      1,   
 10,  "09:00",          18,       0,           0,      1, 
)

#x <- 
  df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(RecordTime)) %>%
  filter(name != "rn") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=RecordTime,y=value,group=name, color=name, fill = name))+
  geom_area()
```

Results:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! This was just what I was looking for. I'm trying this out right now and getting an error: "Error in df %>% pivot_longer(-c(RecordTime)) %>% filter(name != "rn") %>%  : could not find function "%>%" 

Should I be defining "%>%" as anything? This could be a totally dumb question, sorry!

Comment: @sanjanap please make sure to enable `tidyverse` library. I belive the `%>%` symbol originates in `dplyr` (which is activated by `tidyverse`).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `tidyverse` approach. You have to format your data to long. In order to display the time you can hack it with `factor()`. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
df %>% pivot_longer(-Time) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(Time),y=value,color=name,group=name))+
  geom_line()+
  xlab('Time')
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Time = c("00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", 
"05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00"), Coursework = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 17L, 18L), Leisure = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Intern = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PD = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 1L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This is incredibly helpful. I had such a hard time figuring out how to organize my data and assign variables, and your explanation provided some much needed clarity!

Answer (score 0):

**This might work:**
ggplot('data', aes('x', 'y')) + geom_smooth(aes(fill = 'variables'), color = 'choose line color') [see how the code will work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3kfl.png)

You'll have to **arrange** the data in a way where your variables (coursework, intern, etc) are in one column.